# Mute vs muted as an adjective

Tags: adjectives

When something has an option to be put into a silent mode, let's say a messaging group you receive notifications for. Once that option is turned on, what would be the correct usage to describe the object:

*Messaging group is mute.*

*Messaging group is muted.*

Does it matter?

Comment: You *mute* a messaging group so that you don't receive notifications. Now the group is *muted*

Comment: Thanks @FumbleFingers Should I delete the question and re-post it in the other group?

Comment: I'd say if you're in a hurry the best way is for you to use the "flag" option to ***ask a moderator*** to migrate the question. I think almost certainly they will do this straight away if you the OP request migration. I'm not a moderator, so I can only cast my vote - but very likely four other users here will agree with me, in which case it will get migrated automatically by the system. In general it's better if we users can deal with such things ourselves rather than needing to get moderators involved.

Comment: @FF RHK Webster's contrasts sense adj (2) _not emitting or having sound of any kind_ with sense (1) _silent; refraining from speech or utterance_. Allowing for broadening to non-audible signals, both OP's versions would seem allowable. Though 'muted' conveys the fact that the state has been chosen.

Answer (score 2):

You can use both but slightly differently:

(The) Messaging group is on 'mute'.

(The) Messaging group is muted.

As the person above said to say that it is mute - refers to a human/animal - whereas a messaging group is not a living thing.

Comment: If you check in a dictionary such as Collins or RHK Websters', you will see that the animate referent is not strictly necessary. But this question should be close-voted for lack of evidence of the reasonable research required on ELU, not answered, Tenakha.

Answer (score 1):

Both the sentences are grammatically correct and meaningful in different ways.

The word mute can be used in several ways and in different forms (noun, adjective and verb)

I have chosen some important definitions from Google that primarily suit the examples given:

adjective

adjective: mute

> > characterized by an absence of sound; quiet.

"the great church was mute and dark"

verb

verb: mute; 3rd person present: mutes; past tense:muted; past participle: muted; gerund or present participle: muting

> > deaden, muffle, or soften the sound of.

"her footsteps were muted by the thick carpet"

Let's take the examples given:

> > 1. Messaging group is mute. (Here mute acts as adjective - refer to the example and definition above)
> > 2. Messaging group is muted. (Here mute acts as past participle - since I have 'muted'(verb), it is muted(past participle), hence it is mute (adjective) )

Since the word has same form for various tensed, it could lead to confusion, but once analyses, it makes sense a great deal.

Thanks.